# Ruby 2D Extracting Information

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I am relatively new to coding and am learning ruby right now. I came across a problem where I have a huge data record (>100k record) consisting of unique ID and another consisting of the date of birth. So it's basically a 2D array. How do I go about creating a method such that every time when I key in method(year), it will give me all the unique ID of those born in the year i choose? And how do I loop this?

The method I tried doing is as follow:

```
def Id_with_year(year)    
 emPloyee_ID_for_searching_year = [ ]  
   employeelist.sort_by!{|a,b|b}  
    if employeelist.select{|a,b| b == year}.map{|a,b| a}    
     return emPloyee_ID_for_searching_year  
    end  
end
```

I should point out that the ID are sorted. That's why I am trying to sort the year in this method so that it will give me all the ID for the year I key in. The output I had was that it returned me [ ] with nothing inside instead of the ID.

Comment: Can you provide an example with expected output. See here for more [info](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Great, however you need to put this information/example in the question by editing it. Then please delete your previous comment as long lines of code are not appropriate for comments:)

Comment: Thanks @sagarpandya82 for letting me know! Still slightly clueless and am figuring my way out! Thanks!

Comment: “huge data record” usually refers to at least billions; 100K is “normal.” :)

Comment: Lol! Thanks for letting me know! Will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sidenote:* methods in ruby are to be named in snake case (this is not mandatory, though.)

The problem you experience is you `return` what was never changed. The below should work:

```
def id_with_year(year)
  employeelist.sort_by(&:last) # sorting by last element of array
              .select{|_,b| b == year} # select
              .map(&:first)    # map to the first element
end
```

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa! Really appreciate the clarification! :)